# JPA Native Query - Parameter causing unknown column error, not being converted to a string

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Having an issue with my simple JPA native query

```
@Query(value =
    "SELECT * FROM transaction " +
    "WHERE " +
    "( :broker IS NULL OR transaction.broker = :broker ) AND " +
    "( :transaction_type IS NULL OR transaction.transaction_type = :transaction_type ) AND " +
    "( :asset_id IS NULL OR transaction.asset_id = :asset_id )", nativeQuery = true)
Optional<List<TransactionEntity>> findAllByParams(@Param("broker") Broker broker,
                                                  @Param("transaction_type") TransactionType transactionType,
                                                  @Param("asset_id") Long assetId);
```

Broker and TransactionType are enums.

- Broker = REVOLUT
- TransactionType = TRADE
- assetId = 6386

Console is showing this as the query being ran

```
SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE ( REVOLUT IS NULL OR transaction.broker = REVOLUT ) AND ( TRADE IS NULL OR transaction.transaction_type = TRADE ) AND ( 6386 IS NULL OR transaction.asset_id = 6386 )
```

Getting this error when running it

```
[2020-10-30 19:23:42] [42S22][1054] Unknown column 'REVOLUT' in 'where clause'
```

Don't understand why the named parameters aren't being converted to Strings. Have tried everything I could think of to try force it to a String and nothing has changed it.

Comment: I think your return value is causing some trouble.  What happens if you change it to `List<TransactionEntity>`?

Comment: The query seems simple enough that you can use JPQL so it will detect the enum types properly. Not sure why it's inserting them as literals, other than maybe not recognizing they should be strings.

Comment: @coladict good suggestion, that did fix my issue. I would still be interested to know why it was inserting them as literals, but for now I'm happy with this solution thanks